# How to get the stereotypes defined in mdg

Tags: enterprise-architect

We have MDG file .XML which is loaded to EA from the ad-din. Now the problem is how can we read all stereotype that are present in the MDG i.e .xml file loaded in ad-din.Is there any way we can check whether the particular stereotype is present in the particular MDG file.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the API doesn't support getting information about UML profiles yet, and the Database does not contain that information, so you will have to scan the xml file directly.